# Function to identify duplicate Python column names and add specific suffixes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several dataframes with certain duplicate column names (they come from Excel files). My data looks a little something like this.

```
original_df= pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [True, False, True],
    'Revenue (USDm)': [1000, 2000, 1500],
    'Location': ['London', 'New York', 'Paris'],
    'Year': [2021, 2022, 2023],
    'Sold Products': [10, 20, 30],
    'Leased Products': [5, 10, 15],
    'Investments': [7, 12, 8],
    'Sold Products.1': [15, 25, 35],
    'Leased Products.1': [8, 12, 16],
    'Investments.1': [6, 9, 11],
    'Sold Products.2': [5, 10, 15],
    'Leased Products.2': [2, 5, 8],
    'Investments.2': [3, 7, 4],
    'QC Completed?': [True, True, False],
})
```

When I read the df, pandas automatically adds the `.1` and `.2` suffixes to the duplicate column names. I tried to write a function that identifies the duplicates and adds a new set of suffixes from a list I provide, while removing the `.1` and `.2` where applicable.

The new suffixes list is `suffixes = ['Vehicles','Electronics','Real Estate']`

The output should look like this:

```
desired_output = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [True, False, True],
    'Revenue (USDm)': [1000, 2000, 1500],
    'Location': ['London', 'New York', 'Paris'],
    'Year': [2021, 2022, 2023],
    'Sold Products - Vehicles': [10, 20, 30],
    'Leased Products - Vehicles': [5, 10, 15],
    'Investments - Vehicles': [7, 12, 8],
    'Sold Products - Electronics': [15, 25, 35],
    'Leased Products - Electronics': [8, 12, 16],
    'Investments - Electronics': [6, 9, 11],
    'Sold Products - Real Estate': [5, 10, 15],
    'Leased Products - Real Estate': [2, 5, 8],
    'Investments - Real Estate': [3, 7, 4],
    'QC Completed?': [True, True, False],
})
```

The column names without any duplicates should remain the same but the columns which are duplicated get added the suffixes in order; If they also have the `.1` and `.2` suffixes, those get removed.

My function is below:

```
def change_colnames(df, suffixes):
    new_columns = []
    seen_columns = {}

    for column in df.columns:
        match = re.match(r'^(.*?)(?:\.\d+)?$', column)  # Match the base column name and optional suffix
        base_column = match.group(1) if match else column  # Get the base column name or keep the original column name

        if base_column in seen_columns:
            idx = seen_columns[base_column]  # Get the index of the base column
            new_column = f"{base_column} {suffixes[idx]}"  # Append the new suffix
            seen_columns[base_column] += 1  # Increment the index for the next occurrence
        else:
            new_column = base_column
            seen_columns[base_column] = 0  # Add the base column with index 0

        new_columns.append(new_column)

    df.columns = new_columns
    return df
```

Unfortunately the first set of duplicate columns (those without the `.1` and `.2` suffixes) stays the same. The output I get is this:

```
wrong_output = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [True, False, True],
    'Revenue (USDm)': [1000, 2000, 1500],
    'Location': ['London', 'New York', 'Paris'],
    'Year': [2021, 2022, 2023],
    'Sold Products': [10, 20, 30],
    'Leased Products': [5, 10, 15],
    'Investments': [7, 12, 8],
    'Sold Products - Vehicles': [15, 25, 35],
    'Leased Products - Vehicles': [8, 12, 16],
    'Investments - Vehicles': [6, 9, 11],
    'Sold Products - Electronics': [5, 10, 15],
    'Leased Products - Electronics': [2, 5, 8],
    'Investments - Electronics': [3, 7, 4],
    'QC Completed?': [True, True, False],
})
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionary by `enumerate` and mapping duplicated values in counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
suffixes = ['Vehicles','Electronics','Real Estate']
d = dict(enumerate(suffixes))

s = original_df.columns.to_series()

new = s.str.replace(r'\.\d+$','', regex=True)

mapped = (new.groupby(new).cumcount()
             .where(new.duplicated(keep=False)).map(d)
             .radd(' - ').fillna(''))

original_df.columns =  new + mapped
```

---

```
print (original_df)
      ID  Revenue (USDm)  Location  Year  Sold Products - Vehicles  \
0   True            1000    London  2021                        10   
1  False            2000  New York  2022                        20   
2   True            1500     Paris  2023                        30   

   Leased Products - Vehicles  Investments - Vehicles  \
0                           5                       7   
1                          10                      12   
2                          15                       8   

   Sold Products - Electronics  Leased Products - Electronics  \
0                           15                              8   
1                           25                             12   
2                           35                             16   

   Investments - Electronics  Sold Products - Real Estate  \
0                          6                            5   
1                          9                           10   
2                         11                           15   

   Leased Products - Real Estate  Investments - Real Estate  QC Completed?  
0                              2                          3           True  
1                              5                          7           True  
2                              8                          4          False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex for that and [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), here with a custom function for flexibility:

```
import re

# identify duplicated columns
dup_cols = original_df.filter(regex=r'\.\d+$').columns

# get the base names of the duplicates
base = dup_cols.str.replace(r'\.\d+$', '').unique()
# ['Sold Products', 'Leased Products', 'Investments']

# craft a pattern
pattern = fr"^({'|'.join(map(re.escape, base))})(\.\d+)?$"
# '^(Sold\\ Products|Leased\\ Products|Investments)(\\.\\d+)?$'
suffixes = ['Vehicles','Electronics','Real Estate']
dic = dict(enumerate(suffixes))

def f(m):
    suffix = m.group(2)
    if suffix:
        suffix = dic.get(int(suffix[1:]), '')
    else:
        suffix = dic[0]
    return m.group(1) + ' - ' + suffix

# replace based on pattern
original_df.columns = original_df.columns.str.replace(pattern, f, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
      ID  Revenue (USDm)  Location  Year  Sold Products - Vehicles  Leased Products - Vehicles  Investments - Vehicles  Sold Products - Electronics  Leased Products - Electronics  \
0   True            1000    London  2021                        10                           5                       7                           15                              8   
1  False            2000  New York  2022                        20                          10                      12                           25                             12   
2   True            1500     Paris  2023                        30                          15                       8                           35                             16   

   Investments - Electronics  Sold Products - Real Estate  Leased Products - Real Estate  Investments - Real Estate  QC Completed?  
0                          6                            5                              2                          3           True  
1                          9                           10                              5                          7           True  
2                         11                           15                              8                          4          False
```